# Puffed lipo battery

Tags: battery-charging, lipo

I had an old laptop battery with 3 lipo batteries inside each 3.7v 4300mAh, 2 of them were fine, one puffed.

I made a powerbank out of good ones and then decided to test puffed one, connected it it to my small solar panel (5w) in an open area.

As soon as battery hit 3.7, it got healed like if it was never puffed, I never heard of anything like that before. Is there a way to test that battery if it is safe for a parallel connection with other two good batteries? I know it is not a good idea but its extra 4300mAh and I am very greedy when it comes to battery capacity.

**Edit:** upon charge, it got puffed up again harder than before, my guess is that there is 50% chance of it exploding judging by the pressure, i will either put it in salt water or power something like a light with it, somewhere outdoor where there is no risk of fire or damage.

**Edit: I put it in salt water and disposed it.**

Comment: The Lazarus Effect in action.

Comment: Maybe do a few test charges (to its max nominal 4.2V) and discharges (to the lowest value of 3.6V - **no lower** ) by itself to see if there's any physical changes to the battery - preferably in some enclosed space so on the off chance it explodes or starts burning you can isolate it in safety. Even then if it's all good I wouldn't put them in parallel with other cells just out of safety paranoia - I always think it worth paying to get identical batteries to use in parallel than taking a chance - especially when theres possiblity of explosion or fire. Can't put a price on safety IMO